# Assembly file \\sv-db1\server\bin\file:\\sv-db1\server\bin\shell.exe was not found

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cab, scsf

We have installed C# 3.5 application in the server. and installed the client app in each client using Map drive.

**All exes are opening fine from Main.exe in the server**. (main.exe developed using Centura languge). But shell.exe (**C# 3.5, CAB, SCSF**) is not opening in client. shows below message.

I am pretty sure that Shell.exe is launched. because this exe is using devExpres control. and ***error message is using DevExpress theme.***

If normal file not found error, message box will have default windows theme. 
[image]

regards,
Anand

Comment: from what I can see from the path - it doesn't look right - you can't have 'file:\\' in the middle of a path string

Comment: Bond:  it is true, but error message is having "Assembly file" is very strange. default windows file not found error will be like "The system cannot find the file specified". it will not have "Assembly file" in the error message. it looks like some .net error.

Comment: Sure, it's a .NET error.  Looks like this started out as a URL, file://path/filename.ext.  Then got interpreted as a Windows pathname, which put the default working directory in front of it.  You'll have to find out where the URL came from.

Comment: I think this error comes from SCSF. Maybe this will help: http://smartclient.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Known%20Issues%3A%20SC-SF%20April%202008%20with%20Visual%20Studio%202008%20and%20SP1%20Beta&ProjectName=smartclient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bet on the duplicated path part. Instead of  `\\sv-db1\server\bin\file:\\sv-db1\server\bin\shell.exe`, I believe it should be `file:\\sv-db1\server\bin\shell.exe` or  `\\sv-db1\server\bin\shell.exe`.